# Function for adding Node to BST crashing program

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to add nodes to my BST tree but the actual function that adds the nodes using recursion is crashing and I am unsure of why. I tried changing `root->left =` to `root =` and the recursion goes 6 times like it should be still isn't outputting what I want.
my sample input is: btw (They are not real people)

```
6
121 Matt   205000 3000 3  2.0  2000 35 Blueberry Lane
163 Amy  450000 5000 5  5.5   2016  8885 Winter Garden Drive
116 Grant 375000 3000 3 2.0  2015  191 Oviedo Lakes
100 Linda  355000  4000 4 2.5  2014  79 Bradmore Lane
155 Amy  495000  3500  3 3.0   2012  52 Lenox Drive
280  Grant 950000 5000  5   6.5  2016  223 Willow Pines
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ADD_LENGTH 30

typedef struct treeType{
    int listingId, price, propertySize;
    int numOfBeds, yearBuilt;
    double numOfBaths;
    char agent[20];
    char address[ADD_LENGTH];
    struct treeType *left;
    struct treeType *right;    
}bNode;

bNode* addTreeNode(bNode *tree, bNode temp);
void printTree(bNode *root);
bNode* getNewNode(bNode *data);



int main(void)
{
    bNode *root = NULL;
    int numOfProperties;
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("library.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("fopen failed\n");
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &numOfProperties);
    printf("%d\n", numOfProperties);
    bNode temp;
    for(i = 0; i < numOfProperties; i++){
    fscanf(fp,"%d %s %d %d %d %lf %d %[^\n]s", &temp.listingId, temp.agent,&temp.price,&temp.propertySize,&temp.numOfBeds,
           &temp.numOfBaths,&temp.yearBuilt,temp.address);
    root = addTreeNode(root, temp);
    }
    printTree(root);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

bNode* getNewNode(bNode* temp){
    bNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(bNode));
    newNode = temp;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;

}

bNode* addTreeNode(bNode *root,bNode temp){
   printf("Hey boisadd\n");
    if(root==NULL){
        printf("Only Once\n");
        root = getNewNode(&temp);
    }
    else if(temp.listingId < root->listingId){
        root = addTreeNode(root->left, temp);
    }
    else{
        root = addTreeNode(root->right, temp);
    }
    return root;
  /* printf("%d %s %d %d %d %.1lf %d %s\n", (*tree)->node->listingId, (*tree)->node->agent, (*tree)->node->propertySize,(*tree)->node->price, (*tree)->node->numOfBeds,
           (*tree)->node->numOfBaths, (*tree)->node->yearBuilt, (*tree)->node->address);*/
}
```

EDIT: solved problem by changing getNodeFunction

```
bNode* getNewNode(bNode temp){
    bNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(bNode));
    strcpy(newNode->address,temp.address);
    newNode->listingId = temp.listingId;
    newNode->price = temp.price;
    newNode->numOfBaths = temp.numOfBaths;
    newNode->numOfBeds = temp.numOfBeds;
    newNode->propertySize = temp.propertySize;
    newNode->yearBuilt = temp.yearBuilt;
    strcpy(newNode->agent,temp.agent);


    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;

}
```

Comment: What output do you want, and what do you get instead?

Comment: @ScottHunter  i am trying to add the nodes to the tree and eventually print the tree.

Comment: @ScottHunter I actually fixed the problem but I'm not sure how it  is a better solution as if I had a lot of datafields in my struct it would be a chore.

Comment: You didn't actually answer my question :).  Couldn't you just use `*newNode = *temp`, since all of the fields are directly in the struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are 2 problems. First is the node assignment operation in function getNewNode, which should be like this:

```
bNode* getNewNode(bNode* temp) {
    bNode* newNode = (bNode*)malloc(sizeof(bNode));
    // newNode = temp;

    newNode->listingId = temp->listingId;
    newNode->numOfBaths = temp->numOfBaths;
    newNode->numOfBeds = temp->numOfBeds;
    strcpy(newNode->agent, temp->agent);
    strcpy(newNode->address, temp->address);
    newNode->price = temp->price;
    newNode->propertySize = temp->propertySize;
    newNode->yearBuilt = temp->yearBuilt;

    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

And the second problem is when you add child to its parent, you return the child node which should be assignment to child not its parent.

```
bNode* addTreeNode(bNode *root, bNode temp) {
    printf("Hey boisadd\n");
    if (root == NULL) {
        printf("Only Once\n");
        root = getNewNode(&temp);
    }
    else if (temp.listingId < root->listingId) {
        root->left = addTreeNode(root->left, temp);
    }
    else {
        root->right = addTreeNode(root->right, temp);
    }
    return root;
    /* printf("%d %s %d %d %d %.1lf %d %s\n", (*tree)->node->listingId, (*tree)->node->agent, (*tree)->node->propertySize,(*tree)->node->price, (*tree)->node->numOfBeds,
    (*tree)->node->numOfBaths, (*tree)->node->yearBuilt, (*tree)->node->address);*/
}
```